# Can I use Ant with NetBeans PHP projects?

Tags: php, netbeans, ant

I would like to use Ant with some of my PHP projects but I'm not sure how. I tried creating a build script with a few targets but couldn't execute any of them from within Netbeans - there's simply no option to. Is this feature supported in this context or not? If yes, then how do I use it (I must obviously be missing something in this case). I'm using NetBeans 6.7.1 (Ant plugin is installed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. It's described on [sun blog](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/ant_support_on_php_projects) and according to date of the post, the posibility is here for long time

Comment: Right, but it doesn't work out of the box. I had to set JAVA_HOME environment variable to be able to use Ant with PHP projects.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [this patch I created that adds ant support to PHP](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=195706), enabling the build/clean functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is an option or solution in netbeans (at least as external tool as in eclipse), but you could set up an continous integration system like cruiser control for build your project by version control system. There is an easy to use wrapper for cc created for PHP, named PHPunderControl. PHPUC uses Ant, PHPUnit, PHPCS as well.
Take a look at it: [PHPUC](http://www.phpundercontrol.org/)