# How to run some Ant tasks in PHP project in Netbeans 6.8

Tags: php, netbeans, ant

I wanted to run some Ant scripts from a build.xml in my PHP project. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775049/can-i-use-ant-with-netbeans-php-projects) and link talk about a Ant plugin but i cannot find it in NB 6.8.

**Update** & **Closed**

The only way i found to get the Run Target contextual menu is to copy a build.xml from a Java project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ant module is propably already included in your installation (if you choose java, j2ee or "all"). Write a build.xml File and try to open it (dont edit but expand the tree) in the File view instead of the project view.

Answer (score 1):

The Ant module (if not installed by default) can be retrieved using Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins.